# React Select MenuList Props

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

```js
 const { MenuList } = components;
  const CustomMenuList = ({ ...props }: any) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
      <div>
        <MenuList {...props} />
        <hr className="m-0" />
        <div
          className="text-primary p-2  font-weight-bold c-pointer"
          onClick={() => history.push(CUSTOM_POST.replace(':type', 'contact-roles'))}
        >
          + Create New Role
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

I am using TypeScript.
I am using Custom Component in ReactSelect.

What could be the type of props.
I am not allowed to used any because of tslint.

```js
<Select
          components={{
            MenuList: CustomMenuList,
          }}
          options={[...contactRoleOptions]}
         
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-select exports MenuListComponentProps<OptionType>
If you have not added anything then it should be just that...

OptionsType being the type you pass to options

```
Menu.d.ts
export type MenuListComponentProps<OptionType> = CommonProps<OptionType> &
  MenuListProps &
  MenuListState;
```

Comment: @MohammedMak I am glad it was what you were after, could you mark this as the accepted answer then please?